# MySQL: normalize column from big subquery

Tags: mysql

I have a very big subquery:

```
(SELECT Id, Count [...] FROM Something) Counts
```

I want to create a score for each Id that is the count divided by the max count.

I tried:

```
SELECT Id, Count/(SELECT MAX(Count)) AS Score 
FROM (SELECT Id, Count [...] FROM Something) Counts
```

But this only returns the first row!

If I do a `GROUP BY Id`, all scores are equal to 1 (because the maximum is taken for each Id, and not for all Ids).

Do you know what I can do please? I know that in some contexts we can embed a subquery in a `WITH` clause, but this is not valid in MySQL.

Comment: can you please be a little less accurate in describing your problem, because we might even understand what you are trying to do if you go like this

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you need:

Select Id, (Count/(SELECT MAX(Count) FROM Something)) As [Score] FROM Something

Explanation:
I believe you want to take max of all counts in the table. In order to do so you need to perform a subquery on the entire set of the table, versus limiting it to a specific id, or grouping it. When you performed your group by operating on ID, assuming each Id is unique, it is effectively returning Id, Count/Count. As you know any non-zero number divided by itself is 1.

Comment: The thing is that the subrequest is very large. I don't simply take Id and Count FROM Something. There are a lot of intermediate steps, that take 5 or 6 lines that I don't want to copy/paste.